# How do I call a function within an IIFE expression

Tags: javascript, iife

Just started out learning js and using the book Javascirpt an Absolute Beginner's Guide. Question is from an example in the book:

```
var awesomeSauce = (
    function () {     
        var secretCode = "Zorb!";
        function privateCheckCode(code) { 
            if (secretCode == code) { 
                alert("You are awesome!");   
            } else { 
                alert("Try again!");   
            }     
        }
    // the public method we want to return     
        return { 
            checkCode: privateCheckCode     
        }; 
    })();
```

Question is how do I go about to call this code?

```
awesomeSauce("Zorg!");
```

doesnt work and neither does

```
awesomeSauce().privateCheckCode("Zorg!");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awesomeSauce.checkCode("Zorg!");
```

The IIFE returns an object with the `checkCode` property, that property is the (private) function.

The point of the IIFE is that this scopes the variables and functions within, so that they are not accessible from outside (e.g. `privateCheckCode` and `secretCode` exist only inside the IIFE).

Think of the returned object as an "export" of selected values or functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var awesomeSauce = (
    function () {     
        var secretCode = "Zorb!";
        function privateCheckCode(code) { 
            if (secretCode == code) { 
                alert("You are awesome!");   
            } else { 
                alert("Try again!");   
            }     
        }
    // the public method we want to return
        return ( 
            privateCheckCode     
        ); 
    })();
awesomeSauce('Zorb!')
```

hey i don't know much but i happened to solve this: return statement return an expression not a code block. just go through the code i guess you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Lucero's answer

> 1) The IIFE gets executed
>
> 2) result of the execution gets assigned to awesomeSauce

So what is the result of execution ?

It is whatever the function returned, below code

```
return { 
    checkCode: privateCheckCode     
};
```

In this case, it returns an object with a property named "checkCode" which refers to inner function "privateCheckCode".

In short, it becomes,

```
awesomeSauce = { 
    checkCode: privateCheckCode     
};
```

Therefore, you can call your function like this `awesomeSauce.checkCode("Zorb!");`

Comment: Read this "How to Access Properties on an Object" topic in this link http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/

Answer (score 0):

You can call it with `console.log(awesomeSauce.checkCode('Zorb!'));`

as the iife returns an object which has checkCode key and the privateCheckCode as the value.